# Show that if $\sum b_n$ is a rearrangement of a series $\sum a_n$ , and $a_n$ diverges to $\infty$, then $\sum b_n = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I was presented with the following problem;

Show that if $\sum b_n$ is a rearrangement of a  series $\sum a_n$ , and $a_n$ diverges to $\infty$, then $\sum b_n = \infty$.

How would one solve this? It seems intuitively true, but how could I show it?

Comment: The series $1+1-1+1+1-1+\dots$ diverges to infinity, but $1-1+1-1+\dots$ simply oscillates.

Comment: The series 1+1-1+1-1 does not diverge to infinity. It diverges, but not to infinity.

Comment: OP, How is a rearrangement of an infinite series defined? Because the first series @lulu gives does diverge to infinity. But to me it is not trivial $1+1−1+1+1−1+\ldots$ is a rearrangement of $1−1+1−1+\ldots$, as you are messing with the numbers of $-1$ and $+1$ terms...

Comment: @Aex.  the partial sum, $S_n$ of that series is bounded below by $\lfloor \frac n3\rfloor$.  To be clear, the series is defined by $a_n=-1$ if $3|n$, $a_n=1$ otherwise.

Comment: @lulu: are you sure you obtain the first from the second by simply rearranging the terms?

Comment: @Alex.  Yes.  But, of course it isn't true for my sequence that the terms individually got to $\infty$.  I read the question to mean that we were assuming that $\sum a_n\to \infty$.  If, as the posted solution reasonably suggests, the question intended $a_n\to \infty$ then my example is not relevant (and the posted solution looks complete).

Comment: @lulu: The first series in your example is $+1+1-1,+1+1-1,+1+1-1$ and so on, so when you rearrange it by swapping each -1 with preceding +1, you get $+1-1+1+1-1+1+1-1+1$ and so on, so there is always and 'extra' +1 ter, so the series grows. The second series is $+1-1+1, -1+1-1, +1-1+1$ and so on, so when you swap +1 with the preceding -1 you get $+1+1-1+1-1+1$ and so on, which is not the first series (and indeed oscillates). Am I wrong?

Comment: @Alex.  It depends what you mean by a permutation.  If you require that there is some bounded distance $N$ such that no element "moves" more than $N$ terms over, then my example is not a permutation.  But if you allow arbitrary shifts then I am fine. There are infinitely many $1's$ and infinitely many $-1's$ so just take from whichever pile you need to.

Comment: @Alex if you want an explicit rearrangement, let $b_{2n}=a_{3n}$, $b_{4n+1}=a_{3n+1}$, $b_{4n+3}=a_{3n+2}$.  Again, I clearly need to go "further and further out" to grab that next $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean that $a_n\to +\infty$. Under this assumption, we can proceed as follows.

Let $M>0$ be an arbitrary number. Then there is some $N>0$ such that $a_n>1$ for any $n>N$. Since $\{b_n\}$ is a rearrangement of $\{a_n\}$, then there is some $N'>0$ such that $a_1,\ldots,a_N$ are contained in $b_1,\ldots,b_{N'}$.

Set $B=\sum_{k=1}^{N'}b_k$. Then for any $T>|B|+M+N'$, we have 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{T}b_k=\sum_{k=1}^{N'}b_k+\sum_{k=N'+1}^{T}b_k\ge B+(T-N')>M.$$

Therefore, $\sum b_n\to+\infty$.

If we only know $\sum a_n=+\infty$, we can say nothing about $\sum b_n$. See [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).